# Product of dirac delta function without integral

Tags: distribution-theory

I am learning Distribution theory.
I see that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \delta(x) \,dx = f(0)$

The question is, at x=0, is $f(x) \delta(x) = f(0)$, even without integration?
Because at one place, it says $\delta(x)$ is infinitely large at $x = 0$ ( In that case the above expression becomes $f(x)$ times $\infty$). And at other place I see expressions like $f(x) \delta(x)$ used i.e without integrals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, $f(x)\,\delta(x)$ does *not* equal $f(0)$ without integration. It does however equal $f(0)\,\delta(x).$

Comment: So does it mean that, the value of expression involving Dirac delta function comes only when we integrate? Is it wrong to ask what is the value of $f(0)\delta(x)$ at x = 0 ?

Comment: Yes, in general a distribution does not have a global nor local value but we need to "integrate" it (rather: apply it on a test function). It *is* wrong to ask for the value of $\delta(x)$ or $f(x)\,\delta(x)$ or $f(0)\,\delta(x)$ at $x=0.$ Only in the case $f(0)=0$ we can give a meaningful value ($0$).

Answer (score 0):

If one writes $f(x) \delta(x)$, it means you are seeing the outcome as a function over the real numbers. In this context, the rigoruos way of understanding this is not using the Dirac $\delta$ but the function whose value is $0$ at $1$ and $0$ otherwise. If you write $f \delta$ in distribution theory it means that we are considering the application of the distribution $\delta$ to $f$, i.e. $\langle \delta , \phi \rangle$.

If used within an integral, it is a deterministic probability measure ($\delta(x) dx = d \delta$ and the integral over the whole domain is $1$) where the outcome is $0$ with probability $1$. It happens that this later point of view is coherent with the definition of a distribution as it defines a continuous linear form over the space of tests functions by doing : $\langle \delta , \phi \rangle = \int_\mathbb{R} \phi(x) \delta(x) dx = \int_\mathbb{R} \phi(x) d \delta = \mathbb{E}(\phi(X))= \phi(0)$ with $\mathbb{E}$ the expectation operator.

PS : note that is is coherent with the other answer as $f(x) \delta(x) = f(0) \delta(x)$ no matter if you are considering the Dirac $\delta$ or the function that is $1$ only at $0$.

Comment: "the notation $\delta(x)$ denotes a function that is $1$ only at $0$ and $0$ otherwise"
This is incorrect. It is *not* $1$ at $0$.

Comment: The question is about the distribution $\delta,$ not the Kronecker $\delta.$ Those are different things.

Comment: It is meaningful to write $f\delta$ in distribution theory without an integral when $\delta$ is the Dirac distribution.

Comment: The question is tagged with [distribution-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distribution-theory) so the context is distribution theory. Within distribution theory the notation is clear.

Comment: The OP wrote $f(x) \delta (x)$, not $f \delta$, so it is explicitely written as a function over the real numbers, not an evaluation of the $\delta$ distribution over $f$.

Comment: I am also clearing the comment section and i will edit my answer to reflect our discussion since the current version is not clear enough.